# How to know that the cpu management policy is in effect?

Tags: kubernetes

I modified the cpu management policy according to the official document [Control CPU Management Policies on the Node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cpu-management-policies/), but after experiments, I found that the execution time of the task has not been shortened but slightly longer. How do I know that the configuration I modified has taken effect?

I added the following configuration to /var/lib/kubelet/config.yml of each working node,the master node is not modified because it is not scheduled,

```
systemReserved:
  cpu: "4"
  memory: "500m"
kubeReserved:
  cpu: "4"
  memory: "500m"
cpuManagerPolicy: "static"
cpuManagerPolicyOptions:
  full-pcpus-only: "true"
```

deleted cpu_manager_state,restarted the kubelet and started executing tasks, and found that the content of the cpu_manager_state of one of the nodes is

```
{"policyName":"static","defaultCpuSet":"0-7,16-55","entries":{"b0e4cb0d-47b0-4ed3-b707-4baf7eb0875a":{"nf-97cb00a04fbdc660b8193d6093288930":"8-15,56-63"}},"checksum":2824956018}
```

Does this mean that the configuration I modified has taken effect? If it works, why does it take longer to run? Is it related to my k8s version, my k8s version is v1.23.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the QoS class of the pod firstly, and the QoS class must be 'Guaranteed'.